# True or False Linear Algebra Matrix Understanding

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a few true/false statements about matrices that I need help understanding the interpretation of.

### Statement 1: It is possible for a 5x4 matrix to have a rank of 4. (true)

From my understanding, the rank of a matrix is the dimensions of the basis of the column space or range of the matrix. And since the 5x4 matrix has 4 variables, it can have a rank of 4 because there are no underconstrained variables. Could someone correct me on my understanding of this?

### Statement 2: If a 3x4 matrix, then the system Ax=b must have infinitely many solutions for all vectors b in R^3. (false)

I thought this was true because the matrix was underconstrained and therefore any value given for the free variable would output a valid vector in R^3.

Could someone explain these to me ? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In the latter problem it may be the case that there are $b$ such that $Ax=b$ is insoluble.

Comment: For statement 2, I assume you meant to write "If $A$ is a $3 \times 4$ matrix..." But, what if $A$ is the zero matrix?  Of course in that case $Ax = b$ does not have infinitely many solutions if $b$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering that the image of $A$ can span all $\mathbb{R}^3$, in that case yes there will be infinite solutions. But if the image of $A$ cannot span the whole space then there will be $b$s for which there is no solution.

A quick example, if the last row of $A$ is all zeros, then there is no solution for a $b = [0 \quad 0\quad 1]^T$

Also, your first argument is correct.